# is NSException is useful for ios developer and what are the types of its Subclasses

Tags: ios, crash, nsexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone - try, catch question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477416/iphone-try-catch-question)

please tell me that using @try @catch is useful for ios development .
i want to know about the child classes of NSException.
please give me the link to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have missed a part @finally which is the code segment which runs whether the exception is thrown or not and if it is not present the code block after catch block is run.Also, people generally don't use @throw to throw the exceptions.

Anyway it is advisable to use `NSException` if are already aware of your exceptions , you can create and raise the exceptions.

You can have a look at [NSException Apple's Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [About Exceptions and Errors](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/10/13/exceptions-and-errors-on-ios/)

Comment: Than you sir for your advice......

Comment: [Don't use exceptions for everyday error handling.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6477512/19679) Treat them as application-ending errors, and don't throw and catch them like other languages do. For example, under ARC you will leak memory if you throw and catch exceptions. Instead, look to NSError and the like for your regular error handling and recovery.